# SSL-Error while installing apache2

Tags: apache2

I had following error message while installing `apache2` localhost

```
service apache2 reload
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
Syntax error on line 52 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:
SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key' does not exist or is empty
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4):

There are two answers to your question.

The first is the short answer that directly addresses the error in your log:

`file '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key' does not exist or is empty`

Apache is stopping because the SSL certificate is missing. Simply remove the default SSL configuration from the `sites-enabled` folder using `sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl` and Apache should start up no problem. To re-enable the ssl site after you've adjusted the configuration you can run `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl`.

The second answer is the correct answer, which is to take a good look at the Apache documentation to determine why your configuration is incorrect. Because the values in your error log look like the defaults from a fresh Apache install I included the first answer, but after you do the above you should dedicate some time to reading the documentation. You will learn a lot and will find out why there was no `snakeoil.pem` file and what a snakeoil certificate means.

You can find the general documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/

(or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ depending)

You can find general configuration documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

You can find the `mod_ssl` documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like You have forgotten sudo:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a SSL certificate for your server and link the `SSLCertificateFile` (a .crt-file) and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` (a .key-file) to your certificate and certificate key.

This is done in the configuration file which Apache reads on startup. Usually it is located in `/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`. In your case it is located in `/etc/ssl/private/sites-enabled/default-ssl`

To create a self signed certificate follow these [instructions](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)

If you have bought a certificate you simply just locate it and copy the path.